# Crawl html generate by ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to scrape a website page and then save some of the information to my computer, however  some of the website content is generated by ajax.

My question is, can I scrape a site that has ajax generated content?

Comment: Maybe crawl the .js scripts too , get the ajax request link , send a request to that link and store the output .

Comment: i think you can see this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074295/is-there-a-way-to-load-a-xml-file-from-another-domain-using-just-javascript/8074412#8074412

Comment: Have you tried? If so, what happened?

Comment: i can't, only html with no data. i use $ihtml = file_get_html($urlresult);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can see this question

[Is there a way to load a XML file from another domain using just JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074295/is-there-a-way-to-load-a-xml-file-from-another-domain-using-just-javascript/8074412#8074412)

there are how to using proxy in server side programing after that you can call that server by ajax.